# пример Spring4MVCFormValidationExample на русском языке

Tags: java, spring, mvc

прописал по моему уже везде кодировку UTF-8:
в jsp:

```
<% response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"); %>
<% response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");%>
<% request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"); %>
```

в контролере:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = { "text/html;charset=UTF-8" })
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = { "text/html;charset=UTF-8" })
```

в бинах:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value =".jsp" />
        <property name="contentType" value="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>

    </bean>
```

в конфигурации:

```
InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();

    viewResolver.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
```

в web.xml:

```
<jsp-config>
    <jsp-property-group>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
        <page-encoding>UTF-8</page-encoding>
    </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
```

но все равно запрос идет в не верной кодировке и после проверки выдает "ÑÑÐ²" вместо "фыв"

Comment: В хроме нажмите значек настроек - дополнительные инструменты - кодировка - юникод (ютф-8),  страница стала нормальной?

Comment: в хроме кодировка установлена по умолчанию  юникод UTF-8

Comment: Давайте по другому, у Вас стоит параметр в html: `<head><meta charset="UTF-8"></head>`? и добавьте минимальный код jsp страницы, где не верно выдает кодировку, чтоб можно было воспроизвести.

Comment: да конечно стоит <head><meta charset="UTF-8"></head>

Comment: <form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="student" class="form-horizontal">
 
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                <label class="col-md-3 control-lable" for="firstName">Имя</label>
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <form:input type="text" path="firstName" id="firstName" class="form-control input-sm"/>
                    <div class="has-error">
                        <form:errors path="firstName" class="help-inline"/>

Comment: Пробовали добавить фильтр для перекодировки в ютф-8, как [тут](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15992633/6752984)?

Comment: фильтр не добавлял но видать придется....

Comment: Добавил как ответ

Answer (score 1):

вот код формы - после проверки правильности заполнения формы значение в форме меняет кодировку - контролер получает данные в не правильной кодировке:
сообщения о не правильных данных формируются по русски - правильно 
проблема в поле и аналогичных: `<form:input type="text" path="firstName" id="firstName" class="form-control input-sm"/>`

```
<form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="student" class="form-horizontal">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                <label class="col-md-3 control-lable" for="firstName">Имя</label>
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <form:input type="text" path="firstName" id="firstName" class="form-control input-sm"/>
                    <div class="has-error">
                        <form:errors path="firstName" class="help-inline"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                <label class="col-md-3 control-lable" for="lastName">Last Name</label>
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <form:input type="text" path="lastName" id="lastName" class="form-control input-sm"/>
                    <div class="has-error">
                        <form:errors path="lastName" class="help-inline"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                <label class="col-md-3 control-lable" for="sex">Sex</label>
                <div class="col-md-7" class="form-control input-sm">
                    <form:radiobutton path="sex" value="M" />Male 
                    <form:radiobutton path="sex" value="F" />Female
                    <div class="has-error">
                        <form:errors path="sex" class="help-inline"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                <label class="col-md-3 control-lable" for="dob">Date of birth</label>
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <form:input type="text" path="dob" id="dob" class="form-control input-sm"/>
                    <div class="has-error">
                        <form:errors path="dob" class="help-inline"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                <label class="col-md-3 control-lable" for="email">Email</label>
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <form:input type="text" path="email" id="email" class="form-control input-sm"/>
                    <div class="has-error">
                        <form:errors path="email" class="help-inline"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                <label class="col-md-3 control-lable" for="section">Section</label>
                <div class="col-md-7" class="form-control input-sm">
                    <form:radiobuttons path="section" items="${sections}" />
                    <div class="has-error">
                        <form:errors path="section" class="help-inline"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                <label class="col-md-3 control-lable" for="country">Country</label>
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <form:select path="country" id="country" class="form-control input-sm">
                        <form:option value="">Select Country</form:option>
                        <form:options items="${countries}" />
                    </form:select>
                    <div class="has-error">
                        <form:errors path="country" class="help-inline"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                <label class="col-md-3 control-lable" for="firstAttempt">First Attempt ?</label>
                <div class="col-md-1">
                    <form:checkbox path="firstAttempt" class="form-control input-sm"/>
                    <div class="has-error">
                        <form:errors path="firstAttempt" class="help-inline"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                <label class="col-md-3 control-lable" for="subjects">Subjects</label>
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <form:select path="subjects" items="${subjects}" multiple="true" class="form-control input-sm"/>
                    <div class="has-error">
                        <form:errors path="subjects" class="help-inline"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-actions floatRight">
                <input type="submit" value="Register" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form:form>
```

Comment: Добавьте код метода контроллера, где получаете данные и в каком месте кодировка не верная?

Comment: Спасибо тебе огромное, filter помог. Но где то в описании Spring Mvc читал что web.xml вообще не требуется, поэтому старался сделать все таки без него!

Comment: Можно и без него, но он в конфиге все равно добавляется, вот [первый попавшийся пример](http://javastudy.ru/spring-mvc/java-config-web-xml/), где и как это настраивается.

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте в web.xml фильтр для перекодировки в UTF-8 ([отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15992633/6752984)):

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

вот два метода вывожу в протокол объект Student на 0-, 1- сообщения студент пустой еще на 3-уже в неправильной кодировке

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = { "text/html;charset=UTF-8" })
    public String newRegistration(ModelMap model) {
        Student student = new Student();
        System.out.print("0-" + student);
        model.addAttribute("student", student);
        System.out.print("1-" + student);
        return "enroll";
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = { "text/html;charset=UTF-8" })
    public String saveRegistration(@Valid Student student, BindingResult result, ModelMap model) {
        System.out.print("2" + student);
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "enroll";
        }

        model.addAttribute("success", "Dear " + student.getFirstName() + " , your Registration completed successfully");
        return "success";
    }
```